# Multiple join with filtering

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have 3 table 

**Group**

```
idG
```

**Student**

```
idS 
idG
```

**Rating**

```
idR
idS
date
```

relations is 1(Group)-∞(Student),1(Student)-∞(Rating)
I need to select all Group where idG is 1(for example) JOIN Student with LEFT JOIN Rating where date is between.
I trying to use query such this

```
SELECT *
FROM `group` AS g
     JOIN student
        ON g.idG = 1
    LEFT JOIN rating
        ON rating.idR = student.idS
WHERE rating.`date` between '2019-02-01' and '2019-02-28';
```

Result set of this query is student of group which have rating between date,but as I know left join must fetch NULL rating to the student which have no rating between the date. I expecting this result

```
idG | idS | idR  | date|
1   | 1   | NULL | NULL|
1   | 2   | 1    | 2019-02-08|
1   | 3   | 3    | 2019-02-10|
1   | 4   | NULL | NULL|
```

Comment: Move the `date` condition into the last ON clause.

Comment: Change WHERE to AND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the criteria for the left joined table in the JOIN.

```
SELECT grp.idG, stu.idS, rat.idR, rat.`date`
FROM student stu
JOIN `group` AS grp
  ON grp.idG = stu.idG
LEFT JOIN rating rat
  ON rat.idS = stu.idS 
 AND rat.`date` BETWEEN '2019-02-01' AND '2019-02-28'
WHERE stu.idG = 1;
```

The thing with LEFT JOIN is that when you also want those that don't match, that a criteria in the WHERE clause for the joined table will discard all non-matches.
Since it then discards the NULL's on the right side of the join.

Comment: great, in MySQL works perfect. One question, why it cannot be with joining to group student and joining rating to them?

Comment: You could also put that criteria for `idG` in the JOIN.  F.e. `... AS grp ON grp.idG = stu.idG AND grp.idG = 1 ...`.  I merely put it in the WHERE clause because it looked more a search criteria than a link criteria to me.  And the JOIN syntax was created with the intention of separating the "search" and "link" criteria (compared to the outdated comma syntax).  But there's no actual "rule" for this. Often it's a choice (unless the query optimizer generates a slow plan for 1 choice but not for the other)

Comment: As for why the join on `rat.idS = stu.idS `, that's because it makes sense to compare apples with apples, not pineapples.

Comment: make sense, it remains only to translate it all into HQL cause i have duplicate ratings for some reason =(

Comment: Well, I don't know your data or what you actually try to achieve with it.  But maybe you could add a GROUP BY in your query? And use COUNT / MAX / MIN / SUM / ... where appropriate?